# insert to sqlite3 a list of object dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to insert a list of values from dictionary into `sqlite3` database. This is my code and this error appears when I ran the code:

> ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 2 supplied.

```
import sqlite3
import re
import sys
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

ListProduct={'nom_produit':[], 'prix':[], 'note':[]}

ListProduct['nom_produit'].append("Capuche Hip Hop Automne Hiver")
ListProduct['prix'].append('$3.9')
ListProduct['note'].append('4.5')
ListProduct['nom_produit'].append("Capuche Hip Hop Automne Hiver")
ListProduct['prix'].append('$12.9')
ListProduct['note'].append('4.8')

# Permet de se connecter à la base de données
conn = sqlite3.connect("mabase.db")   
    # Initialise le curseur
cur = conn.cursor()

    # Créer la table si elle n'existe pas

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Produit (nom_product VARCHAR,price real, rating real)")

for key,values in ListProduct.items():

     cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Produit(nom_product, price,rating) VALUES(:nom_produit, :prix,:note)""", values)

    # Accepter les changements

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Produit')
meida = cur.fetchone()
print(meida)
conn.commit()

    # Fermer la connexion
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 3 named placeholders: `:nom_produit`, `:prix` and `:note` which makes `sqlite3` to expect `values` to be a dictionary containing `nom_produit`, `prix` and `note` keys.

But, your `values` values are lists.

Change the definition of `ListProduct` to:

```
ListProduct= [
    {
        'nom_produit': "Capuche Hip Hop Automne Hiver",
        'prix': '$3.9',
        'note': '4.5'
    },
    {
        'nom_produit': "Capuche Hip Hop Automne Hiver",
        'prix': '$12.9',
        'note': '4.8'
    }
]
```

Then, you can even avoid the loop altogether and switch to `executemany()`:

```
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        Produit
        (nom_product, price, rating) 
    VALUES
        (:nom_produit, :prix, :note)
""", ListProduct)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but when i executed your code , i have this error ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 29 supplied.

Comment: @Ilyas yeah, there was a mistake in the code, fixed - parameterize with `ListProduct`.